# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xb9 in position 23: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.6, sdna

I used *Prepare Network* but failed. The system is Windows 11, x64. I use ArcGIS 10.6, sDNA 4.0.3.

The error is:

> Executing: sDNAPrepare D:\personal\aaa.mdb\roadroad
> C:\Users\69580\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb\roadroad_sDNAPrepare # #
> REPAIR true false true true false # # # # # # Start Time: Fri Jan 27
> 17:27:53 2023 Running script sDNAPrepare...
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 128, in
> execute UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xb9 in
> position 23: ordinal not in range(128)
>
> Failed to execute (sDNAPrepare). Failed at Fri Jan 27 17:27:55 2023
> (Elapsed Time: 1.48 seconds)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in sDNA: we don't support non-ascii characters in the input data yet. Or in filenames. It's on the todo list.